# Stiil getting duplicate message with SwingWorker

Tags: java, udp, multicast

I ask a question related to this one but i'm getting the same error, and i don't know what to do.

[PREVIOUS QUESTION](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48099018/dupplication-of-message-from-server-on-textarea)

I made a simple multicast chat, but i'm getting the messages duplicated. 
I try use the solutions in the answers but indeed.

So, i try to make a small project only send a message to the server "hello" and getting the same issue.

I use only this three files to testing what is going on:

```
public class NewClass {

    private static DatagramPacket packet;
    private static Object sds;



    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            String messageMultiCast = "Hello";
            MulticastSocket socketMulti = new MulticastSocket(5000);
            InetAddress ip = InetAddress.getByName("239.255.0.1");

            socketMulti.joinGroup(ip);


            try {

                byte[]  buf = messageMultiCast.getBytes();

                packet = new DatagramPacket(buf, buf.length, ip, 5000);


                socketMulti.send(packet);

                byte[] bufx = new byte[65535];

        while (true) {

            try {
                DatagramPacket packet1 = new DatagramPacket(bufx, bufx.length);
                socketMulti.receive(packet1);

              String  receive = new String(packet1.getData(), 0, packet1.getLength());

              System.out.println("O cliente recebeu:"+receive);


            } catch (IOException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(NewClass.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }

        }
            } catch (UnknownHostException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(NewClass.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(NewClass.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }
```

**SERVER SIDE**

```
    public class ser {

        /**
         * @param args the command line arguments
         */
        public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
            new multicastserverthred().start();
        }

    }
```

**THREAD**

```
/**
 *
 * @author Zé Luís
 */
public class multicastserverthred extends Thread {
       private final String DEFAULT_MULTICASTIP = "239.255.0.1";
    private final int DEFAULT_MULTICASTPORT = 5000;
    private final int FIVE_SECONDS = 5000;
    private DatagramPacket packet;
    private JTextArea textA;
    private boolean moreQuotes = true;
    private MulticastSocket socket = null;

    private InetAddress adresstoConnectMulticast = null;

    public multicastserverthred() throws IOException {



    }

    public void run() {


            while (true) {

                try {
                    byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
                    socket = new MulticastSocket(DEFAULT_MULTICASTPORT);
                    adresstoConnectMulticast = InetAddress.getByName(DEFAULT_MULTICASTIP);

                    socket.joinGroup(adresstoConnectMulticast);
                    packet = new DatagramPacket(buf, buf.length); //usado para receber um datagram do socket, o array
                    socket.receive(packet);

                    String mensagem = new String(packet.getData()).trim();

                   System.out.println("\n\nServer Multicast Receive from User:" + mensagem + " on IP Multicast " + DEFAULT_MULTICASTIP + " | " + DEFAULT_MULTICASTPORT);

                    buf = mensagem.getBytes();

                    //manda de volta para o cliente.
                    DatagramPacket packets = new DatagramPacket(buf, buf.length, adresstoConnectMulticast, DEFAULT_MULTICASTPORT);
                    socket.send(packets);

                } catch (IOException ex) {
                    Logger.getLogger(multicastserverthred.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);

                }

            }

        }
```

The `System.out.println` prints two times the message.

Comment: Does you client need to create a new `Socket` on each loop?

Comment: Where's the server code? How is anyone expected to run the code? Also, this has nothing to do with `SwingWorker`

Comment: Server Side is Server Code, the server need's to receive message from the client, because i need to use a protocol and then send to all clients in multicast group. SwingWorker is in previous question because the people though  the problem can be related to the GUI.

Comment: if a put the multicast socket inside the loop, give a infinitive....

Comment: Spreading your code across multiple questions isn't helpful.  Based on your description, it sounds like what's happening is. The client is sending a message to the server, the server is then broadcasting that message to all clients (including the originator), which is then producing the duplicate message issue. You have two basic solutions; 1- Either ignore any broadcast messages which are duplicates of any outgoing messages OR rely on the broadcast message to update the state of the conversation;

Comment: 2- Don't use broadcasting and simply maintain a list of clients on the server and only send the messages to the clients which didn't originate the message

Comment: i think that i made it, please follow me... on server side i add instead of send on packet the adress...  i made `String ad = packet.getAdress` and all users receive the message and not duplicated. You think that is correct?